# Spring :How to generate WSDL at run time if XSD provided as input

Tags: soap, xsd, jaxb, wsdl, spring-ws

I have to create simulator where on run time WSDL files can be generated if XSD file is given as input. For this i am using Spring Web Services and JAXB API to generate WSDL from given XSD file.

After all the sample programs , i have understood that java classes can be generated with help of JAXB  on running  maven file but still we need to manually write the serviceEndpoint class , hence it seems difficult to generate ServiceEndpoint class for the given xsd file.

I want to know is it possible to generate serviceEndpoint class as well for the given xsd on the run time and compiled as well.

In short i want to automate whole process of WSDL generation if XSD file is given as input as runtime.

Comment: First of all, WSDL is used to describe a web service. i.e. when you create a WDSL, you have to define the operations and the type of transport used for the webservice communication. XSD is a schema file used to deine the messages used as input/output to a web service operation. how is it possible to identify the behaviour of your service and the mode of communication from an XSD file?   Again, JAXB is a way of parsing the XML document and not for generating java classes.Correct me if i understood it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Spring automatically exposes the WSDL generated from your configuration. See section 5.3.1.1 from the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d0e1664)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use `ServletRegistrationBean` with defined URL mapping, etc., like this:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
      servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
      servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
      return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

If your XSD schema is named test.xsd then you can access your WSDL at runtime here: http://localhost:8080/ws/test.wsdl